# SSIS Conditional Split Reject files

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I want to migrate the data to a target table.
However, I want to make a reject file for null values ​​and values ​​whose size exceeds 20 characters. As I do with Conditional Splitting?
I did that but it doesn't work:

```
"if len(mail)>10 caractère"
```

i will export this values to reject file

How can i do this Please ?

Comment: Can you please give a little more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Design

You can do this directly in a conditional split but I advise against doing so. Instead, compute the boolean (true/false) condition in a Derived Column and add that to your data flow. Then, if you get unexpected results, you can add a data viewer between the Derived Column step and the Conditional Split

### Implementation

Add a Derived Column to the data flow. Add a new column called `BadMail`. If it's true, then we'll route to the bad file. If it's true, it will proceed to the destination.

The Expression language for SSIS will use the ternary operator `(test) ? true_condition : false_condition`

I am going to test for null `ISNULL(mail)`, longer than 20 `len(mail) > 20` and zero length `len(mail) == 0`.

The `||` is a logical or so if any of those three conditions are true, then we need to set the BadMail to true

```
(ISNULL(mail) || len(mail) > 20 || len(mail) == 0) ? true : false
```

You could simplify that to eliminate the ternary operator but I find being explicit in my intentions helpful in these situations. As a side note, if you are still having issues with unexpected results, add a preceding Derived Column transformation and add a column in for each criteria (null, 0 or greater than 20 character) and then you can inspect them individually.

Now, we add the Conditional Split

The expression here is just our new column `BadMail` and that will route to Output Path 1 or whatever you name it. The good mail will pass through to the default output path.